# CustomPushHandler delegate not being called deep linking urban airship

Tags: ios, objective-c, urbanairship.com, deep-linking

Hello im trying to do the deep linking feature in my app but the callbacks arent being called when i tap on the notification and the app opens.
Im following this tutorial: https://support.urbanairship.com/customer/portal/articles/1087599-custom-push-handling-in-ios---deep-linking-from-a-push-notification-to-a-url.

Here´s how it looks like the appDelegate:

```
customPushHandler = [[CustomPushHandler alloc] init];
[UAPush shared].pushNotificationDelegate = customPushHandler;
UAConfig *config = [UAConfig defaultConfig];
[UAirship takeOff:config];
[UAPush shared].notificationTypes = (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound |
UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert 
);
[UAPush setDefaultPushEnabledValue:NO];
[[UAPush shared] setPushEnabled:YES];
[[UAPush shared] resetBadge];
```

And These are the headers of the CustomPushHandler:

```
- (void)displayNotificationAlert:(NSString *)alertMessage;
- (void)receivedBackgroundNotification:(NSDictionary *)notification fetchCompletionHandler:(void ( ^ ) ( UIBackgroundFetchResult result ))completionHandler;

- (void)launchedFromNotification:(NSDictionary *)notification fetchCompletionHandler:(void ( ^ ) ( UIBackgroundFetchResult result ))completionHandler;

- (void)receivedForegroundNotification:(NSDictionary *)notification fetchCompletionHandler:(void ( ^ ) ( UIBackgroundFetchResult result ))completionHandler;
```

The only callback called is displayNotificationAlert that is being called when the app is running. When the app is in background i receive the notification, i tap on it, the app opens but there is no callback called.

I dont know what im doing wrong.
Thanks for reading.

Comment: Same problem here. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Are remote notifications enabled for the app? http://docs.urbanairship.com/build/ios_features.html#background-push

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by dperconti in the comments:

Enabling remote notifications for the app fixed this for me:

http://docs.urbanairship.com/build/ios_features.html#background-push